# Calling ajax from radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an input like:

```
 <input id="offline-42" onclick="javascript:checkoutSwitch(false);controlDivPayment('42');" name="payment" type="radio" value="offline-42"  />
```

I'm trying to use ajax to add a product to the shopping cart when this radio button is selected. I'm trying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#offline-42').submit(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'add_cart.asp',
                data: {
                    quick: 1
                    item_id: 16
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

However this does nothing when the button is selected, nor are there any errors in the chrome debugger. I think I'm missing something simple, but not sure what.

Comment: submit() on a input element?

Comment: @null i'm very new to javscript,jquery and ajax. was following some online guides... "wisdom of the internet". Should this be `.select()` instead?

Comment: 1.) the "javascript:" protocol in your onclick handler is redundant. 2.) what is your server returning? JSON? if so the getJSON() method might be easier for you to use. 3.) What are you planning to do with the data when you get it?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle! :D

Comment: @scunliffe the `input` was created by our ecommerce provider, i'm just trying to augment the functionality to add a product when this radio button is selected. (i'd like to avoid changing their stuff as much as possible).

Comment: @scunliffe the purpose is to post this URL without refreshing the page: `add_cart.asp?quick=1&item_id=16`  .. i tried using an iframe already with just normal javascript, but it "jumps" the focus of the window to the iframe, even if it's a 1x1 pixel iframe.

Comment: @SnakeDoc what is coming back from the AJAX call? some JSON data? an HTML fragment? XML?

Comment: @scunliffe i think it's html. but i can ignore it. when you manually append that URL to the page you are on and hit "enter", it just refreshes the current page you are on, but the item has been added to the cart. so it doesn't actually take you anywhere nor change data displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are searching for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#offline-42').closest('form').submit(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'add_cart.asp',
            data: {
                quick: 1
                item_id: 16
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

It attaches an event handler to the form and not to the radio control, and also `return false;` so the page won't refresh.